# Using XMLHttpRequest object to PHP, responseText is correct array, but 500 error thrown. Cannot identify cause of error

Tags: php, yii, xmlhttprequest, phpexcel

I've been working on reading an Excel file using PHPExcel and sending the contents of the active worksheet through a JSON encoded array back to the page. My code performs as I expect when I load a specific Excel file, in this case cookies, which lives in the path built below. However, if I change the file name (comment cookies and uncomment testLoadBook.xls), and nothing else, the PHP executes returning the correct array (indicating PHPExcel executed properly, seemingly anyway) but throws a 500 error.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . Yii::app()->getBasePath().'/extensions/phpexcel/Classes/');
require_once('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
//$excelFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'cookies.xls';
$excelFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'testLoadBook.xls';

echo $excelFile;

//$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excelFile);


$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5'); //if file extension is .xls
//$excelReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$excelObj = $excelReader->load($excelFile);

$response = array();
$worksheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

$response[] = array($highestRow,$highestColumnIndex);    
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; $col++) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val = $cell->getValue();
        $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);

        $response[] = array($row,$col,$val);
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Echoing the file path shows that the same exact directory is being referenced (both files exist there). The permissions on both files are the same. I've tried two different approaches to loading the workbook:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excelFile);
```

and

```
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5'); //if file extension is .xls
$excelObj = $excelReader->load($excelFile);
$worksheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();
```

Both of these solutions execute properly without error on the cookies.xls workbook.

I apologize for the potentially confusing description, but I cannot think of any reason a 500 would be thrown while the expected output is also returned.

Thanks for anyone's help on this.

Greg

Comment: if you get a server-side 500 error, then check the server's error log for more details.

Comment: Here is the line that is generated in the error log:2013/06/03 14:30:16 [error] 20692#0: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CListIterator' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/private/yiiFrameworks/yii-1.1.13/collections/CList.php on line 90" while reading response header from upstream, request: "POST /greg/importData HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web20.sock:", host: "greg.dev.ces.local", referrer: "http://greg.dev.ces.local/greg/page?view=01_simple_init"

Comment: It seems to me that the Yii framework could be causing the problem. But I'm lost as to why it would successfully upload one document and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to determine the problem that was occurring. Yii was looking for the CList.php file after the PHP script was done executing. Yii was unable to find the class file because Yii had been unregistered via:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

This allowed PHPExcel to properly execute and fill the httpRequest.responseText with the correct array of the specified file. The problem came when the PHP file had finished executing and returned to the JavaScript that had called it. At this point, Yii had been unregistered and never reloaded. The approach below must be used because PHPExcel has its own autoloader and will interfere with Yii.

The solution to the problem was fairly simple once I figured this out:

```
$phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes'); //get path for PHPExcel
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload')); //unload Yii

//include PHPExcel and autoloader will execute automatically
include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel.php');

//do PHPExcel operations: load file, parse and create array, echo JSON array

spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload')); //reload Yii before returning to page
```

REF:
http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/11/05/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-yii/

EDIT: Thanks to SilentSakky above for linking the reference that helped me solve this

Answer (score 1):

The error seems like there is some file required which is not included, you can try this

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
Yii::import('ext.PHPExcel.Classes.PHPExcel', true);
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

---

**Ref:**

1) http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/31998-problem-loading-phpexcel/

Comment: Thanks, this was close - I needed to wrap the PHP Excel operations within the unregister and register functions for YiiBase.