# Yii, php foreach error

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreach

I have this line to query what I need, in a function of a model called `Payment.php`,

```
$sIDs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT service_id FROM booking WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") = "06-2015" AND complete = 1 AND service_id IS NOT NULL')->queryAll();
```

And then my foreach to iterate through the array list of `$sIDs`:

```
foreach ($sIDs as $sID){
        $serMod = Service::model()->findByPk($sID); //This is line 45
        $serPrice = $serMod->defaultPrice; 
        $serviceIncome += $serPrice; 
}
```

Unfortunately, it shows me an error:

> **Fatal Error:** Class 'Service' not found in **F:\xampp\htdocs\wellness\protected\models\Payment.php** on line **45**
>
> **Fatal Error:** Class 'CListIterator' not found in **F:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\collections\CList.php** on line **90**

I've searched through the Internet, looking at the syntax for `foreach` but I'm having the correct syntax already. Is there some point that I might have left out? Please guide me, thanks.

**EDIT**

After further debugging, I was using PHPExcel all along with this line:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

this basically disables anything calling a Yii function or anything.

Comment: did you load the class , ie add this on top of your controller below the namespace statement : `use app\models\Service`?

Comment: i hope you already found out that the problem is not in your foreach statement, but in your general configuration probably

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `foreach`, but that the Class is not found,

Since I do not see the code loaded before the foreach cycle, I cannot tell you why exactly `Service` is not found.
Try to solve that. ANd if you do, try to `vardump` or `print_r` the class, to get a better understanding of what it contains

Comment: There's basically nothing else before the `foreach` except for that SQL statement. I've looked at my other models.php, I have done the same thing creating a new Service model the same way. But for some reason, they work! And not this. Does `CListIterator` affect anything? It has been showing this error .

Comment: seems that they both are not loading, so you need to figure out why they are not loading before you call them. With the info you have included I cannot help much more.

Comment: Basically you are calling a class, or two classes which are not found at the time they have been called, so you need to find out why they are not found/declared

Comment: But isn't `CListIterator` a default thing provided by Yii? There's no way I could've made changes to it. They're auto generated afterall. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check for consistency your database. I mean to check if there some records in table booking which service_id key isn't present in table service ( probably this is the table behind model Service ). You can check this by something query like:

```
SELECT service_id FROM booking WHERE (service_id IS NOT NULL ) AND service_id NOT IN ( SELECT service_id FROM service );
```

Also I think you have to mentioned row to be like this:

```
$serMod = Service::model()->findByPk($sID['service_id']);
```

It is because event you have only one column in query the QueryAll returns it in array of 1-dimension arrays.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. But I've checked in my database using the same SQL statement as stated and it does return records. There are records of what I need. But for some reason, it's throwing me errors.

Comment: And are you sure you got this one file in model directory? May be it is ServiceS or some other stupisd sintax error. Also if you created it manualy not by GRUD then check also into class file if the class definition is with right name too.

Comment: Everything is fine. The other models calling the same Model and it's working fine. Same model creation of the Service model and they all worked properly. ALSO in a `foreach` cycle.

Comment: I'm sure it is something stupid that can eat the head - please try this:  $serMod = Service::model()->findByPk($sID['service_id']);

Comment: I've tried it. It's still not working. I've tried using a primary key of Service, i.e. 1 // 2 // 3. It is also not working. I'm guessing it's not about the `findByPk` that is giving the problem. It is `Service::model` which is giving problem.

Comment: it has to be defined like a static and public, but if you created by GRUD, then it is. And if you tried to call it outside of foreach ? - I mean in same this function - without foreach - single call with some ID - like you noted above?

Comment: Still the same, it's the `Service::model()`'s problem already.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PHPExcel with this line:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

So, of course calling a function which needs other models will be disable. For example calling a function to create a model `Servce::model()->findByPk()` will be disabled.

Therefore, do the appropriate function before the line above and attach it to a variable. Now you can use it anywhere in the controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

hi is this for get excel report .Yii was looking for the CList.php file after the PHP script was done executin

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

This allowed PHPExcel to properly execute and fill the httpRequest

The solution to the problem was fairly simple once I figured this out

```
$phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes'); //get path for PHPExcel

spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload')); 
include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel.php');
//do PHPExcel operations: load file, parse and create array, echo JSON array
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload')); //reload Yii before
```

REF :[Using XMLHttpRequest object to PHP, responseText is correct array, but 500 error thrown. Cannot identify cause of error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903141/using-xmlhttprequest-object-to-php-responsetext-is-correct-array-but-500-error)